# How to create new column based on multiple conditions?

Tags: sas

I have two columns and would like to create a third.  The logic that I am       trying to create is;
Column A represents a unique customer record.  For every unique customer based on email or ID number in column A I would like to look at column B and if there is a mix of POS and Web then the third column = MC, if not then non MC.

```
Column A             Column B   Column C
test@test.com         POS        MC
test@test.com         POS        MC
test@test.com         WEB        MC
test123@test.com      POS        not MC
123456                POS        MC
123456                WEB        MC 
123458                WEB        not MC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a `PROC SQL` :

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as
  select h1.A, h1.B, h2.UNIQUE_B, case when h2.UNIQUE_B = 1 then 'Not MC' else 'MC' end as MC
  from have h1
       left join
       (select A, count(distinct(B)) as UNIQUE_B
        from have
        group by A) h2 on h1.A = h2.A 
  order by h1.A ;
quit ;
```

Comment: thanks - could you just clarify, I don;t actually have column C as that is what I;m trying to get to, so are h1.A and h1.B referring to columns A and B?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - removed reference to `h1.C`. All the references to `A` / `h1.A` / `h2.A` / `B` / `h1.B` are your two columns, and `MC` is the result column you're after.

Answer (score 0):

ok so just so I understand, where Column A is "ID" and Column B is "channel" in my data set, I've changed the code accordingly, but the log is throwing quite a few errors around ambiguous so I guess I've missed something here with your references.  Does the code look correct?

```
proc sql ;
  create table Aimee.MCreport as
  select ID, Channel, Channel.UNIQUE_Channel, case when Channel.UNIQUE_Channel = 1 then 'Not MC' else 'MC' end as MC
  from Aimee.Weekly_Email_files_cleaned3 ID
       left join
       (select ID, count(distinct(Channel)) as UNIQUE_Channel
        from Aimee.Weekly_Email_files_cleaned3
        group by ID) Channel on ID = Channel
  order by ID ;
quit ;
```